# Pointing dereference inside a struct error

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, dereference, circular-list

i have a function to create a circular list, i am having issues compiling, not sure if it is syntax, appreciate if someone can help.

```
    void CreateCircularList(struct node** listRef, struct node** tailRef)

    {    
    Push(&*listRef, "String 1");
    *tailRef=*listRef;
    Push(&*listRef, "String 2");
    Push(&*listRef, "String 3");
    Push(&*listRef, "String 4");

    *(tailRef->next)=*listRef;

    }
```

the compiler flags an error in the last line:

> "Member reference base type 'struct node*' is not a structure or
>   union"

Any ideas why ?  thanks

Comment: If it fails to compile it is related to syntax...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want

```
  (*tailRef)->next = *listRef;
```

as the last assignment.

You cannot write `tailRef->next` since `tailRef` is a pointer to a pointer.

I also suggest just coding  `Push(listRef, "Some string");` instead of your `Push(&*listRef, "Some string");` for readability reasons.

Comment: When you code `tailRef->` you are dereferencing `tailRef`. In *C* `x->y` is exactly the same as `(*x).y` so is a dereference of `x`

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to do it as below

```
(*tailRef)->next = *listRef;
```

i.e get the `struct node *` pointed to by `tailref`, dereference with `->` to get the `struct node *` that is `next` and then set it to the element pointed to by `listRef`